# basic concept for Linear Algebra

Tags: matrix, machine-learning

Question is: Let A and B be 3x3 (square) matrices. Which of following must necessarily hold true?
One of the option is A + B = B + A, but I didn't choose. The answer display this equation is true. I don't understand. In the identity matrix, A * I(n*n) = I * A 
Can this multiply principal also be used in addition? Could you give a specific and simple example? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you don't know how to do your homework, maybe you should ask your teacher?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding Matrices is a element-wise operator:
Note adding is **commutative** which means you can change the order around.

A  = [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
B = [4 9 2 ; 2 0 4 ; 3 6 7]

A + B = [1 + 4 ,2 + 9, 3 + 2; 4 + 2, 5 + 0, 6 + 4; 7 + 3 ,8 + 6, 7 + 9]

B + A = [4 + 1, 9 + 2, 2 + 3; 2 + 4, 0 + 5, 4 + 6; 3 + 7, 6 + 8, 9 + 7]

Notice both operations yield the same result since adding is **commutative** and bit wise adding means adding matrices is also **commutative** so the operands can be swapped! Not too sure about your second question though :(

Comment: Thanks for helping